# How can i store more number of records in db in heroku from csv in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I wanted to store more number of records in heroku db and i am importing data from csv file to table and when running it starts producing

```
Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

so how can i avoid this and store all the records in the table in heroku.

Answer (score 0):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r14-memory-quota-exceeded Add more RAM or decrease current usage it.